# How do you change the install location of a visual studio project?

Tags: visual-studio

How do you change the install location of a visual studio project? By this, I mean when you run the Install target, the location of the resulting install tree rather than the location of visual studio itself.

Comment: which extension you are using to build your setup?

Comment: I generated solution files with cmake and then opened the project in the gui. Problem is that I got the cmake install prefix wrong and want to change without regenerating and rebuilding.

Comment: then out of my league!